# If action is on a different page do I use fwrite function

Tags: php

I have a form that has an action of a GET on another page.. IT also has a post method that I am using to write form data too .txt file.. When I have an action of (action="") it writes to .txt file but when I have an action on a different page (action="somepage.php?getthings") it does not write to txt file.. is there a fix to this?

```
<?php
//Get the email from POST
$email = $_REQUEST['EMAIL'];
$file = fopen("document.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$email . "\n");


//redirect
?>



    <form id="subscribe-form1" action="THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS"
    method="post" class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="EMAIL">

        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-grn" type="submit button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="submit" value="submit" action="" >Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="visibility:collapse;" id="subscribe-result1"> </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mce-group[6917]-6917-0" name="group[6917][1024]" value="1024" checked="checked" style="">
            I agree to recieve FREE newsletter from Personal Trainer Food </label>
        </div>      
      

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a bit confused because you mention the use of both POST and GET. You cannot write to the mailchimp script, and I don't know exactly how your mailchimp form is configured so let's try a different approach. Let's try ajax, even though you did not tag this.

First, **change the action of the form to your mailchimp URL** instead of "". Then create a new PHP file:

```
// this is your ajax file, ajax.php


<?php

    $email = $_POST['EMAIL']; // your form method is post, no need for $_REQUEST
    $file = fopen("document.txt","a+");
    $write = fwrite($file,$email . "\n");

    echo $write ? "Success" : "Fail";
?>
```

Now change your button from type="submit button" to type="button".

You need to add some jQuery:

```
<script>

    function executeAjax() {
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'ajax.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {EMAIL: $("#subscribe-form1").find("input[type='email']"},
                 success: function(data) {
                     alert(data); return false;
                     document.getElementById("subscribe-form1").submit();
                 },
                 error: function(e) {
                     alert('There was a problem...please try again');
                 }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            executeAjax();
        });
    });
</script>
```

After posting the email address to the ajax file on the backend, the file will be written. Then, the form action will be executed.

Comment: Okay the only thing is I am using the action to send email to mailchimp.. and I dont think there is a way to put my script on that page. Is there a way to have the form write to 2 pages? the one im sending to and just the current location?

Comment: OK, so the file needs to be written, and then the post data - after this file write - needs to be sent to mailchimp, right?

Comment: sure. I just need the email that is written in that form to be sent to mail chimp. and also written in a txt file.

Comment: Also, form cannot have 2 actions - I have investigated this and you cannot do it. You need a backend script in 1 location to do multiple things/actions

Comment: OK - will add to my answer

Comment: Thank you! please explain as much detail as possible since I am really new to this php thing.

Comment: im gonna give it a go. be back in a few.

Comment: I made 1 more edit...try to use the current code if possible

Comment: so this is what it looks like when I add extra code... I think I might need to use get instead of post???

Comment: $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://personaltrainerfood.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=4a4dd02f&amp;id=76325114ff");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

Comment: You want this to execute only on form submission, right? And form uses method = post. As long as that URL is correct, it should be ok. To debug, if necessary, add this line right after $result = ....      Add this -> die($result); or die(print_r($result));

Comment: I think it needs to be both GET and POST casue chimp is using GET and POST is so I can write to txt.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. Is the action the mailchimp URL?

Comment: Yes it is a mailchimp URL do you think there is a solution for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my answer so that what I think is happening will actually be successful

Comment: okay thank you! it ends something like this .com/subscribe/post-json?u=4092f&amp;id=76325224ff"

Comment: So basically what is happening is ajax is writing form data to txt file.. then form submits to mail chimp as normal?

Comment: What fails? File write or form submit?

Comment: I can get form to submit to mailchimp just fine. its writing to txt file that is giving me issues.

Comment: 1 last thing and then I am out of ideas - is the ajax script being accessed at all? Can you add this to top of ajax.php ---> die($_POST['EMAIL']); ? Then in chrome developer tools, right click -> Inspect -> Go To Network tab on top and then submit a form. If ajax.php is listed, click on it, then see if the Response tab shows the email address that was typed in is displayed

Comment: So the ajax is never reaching the backend. That's why file not being written. Is ajax.php in the same folder as your file that has the form (from your post above)?

Comment: Last thing then I give up - I edited the ajax script, both backend and frontend. Can you please try these new scripts and let me know if anything is alerted when the submit button is pushed? Remember the button must be type="button"